# Firebase Firestore Backend Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error error:140740B5:SSL routines:SSL23_CLIENT_HELLO:no ciphers

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, okhttp

I am getting this error while running Firestore data fetch in android 4.4.2

I have tried adding the TSL 1.2 support for the app but it is still not fixing the issue with Firestore.

```
1-26 18:50:40.901 16934-17082/package I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [ExponentialBackoff]: Backing off for 33087 ms (base delay: 25624 ms, delay with jitter: 36533 ms, last attempt: 3446 ms ago)
11-26 18:50:44.421 16934-17082/net.insi8.word I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [WriteStream]: (42386850) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=null, cause=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x642b6078: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:140740B5:SSL routines:SSL23_CLIENT_HELLO:no ciphers available (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:486 0x5eceb6fd:0x00000000)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:448)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.negotiate(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:92)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator$AndroidNegotiator.negotiate(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:147)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpTlsUpgrader.upgrade(OkHttpTlsUpgrader.java:63)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$2.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:466)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x642b6078: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:140740B5:SSL routines:SSL23_CLIENT_HELLO:no ciphers available (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:486 0x5eceb6fd:0x00000000)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
    ... 8 more
}.
11-26 18:50:44.422 16934-17082/package I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [ExponentialBackoff]: Backing off for 81781 ms (base delay: 60000 ms, delay with jitter: 81785 ms, last attempt: 4 ms ago)
11-26 18:50:44.423 16934-17082/package I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [WriteStream]: stream callback skipped by CloseGuardedRunner.
11-26 18:50:50.902 16934-17082/package I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds
```

Comment: What was the cause and solution for this problem? I am Also facing in some phones like samsung Android 4.4

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the exact same problem in Android 4.4.

For me, it was Google Play Service being out of date. I found in my logs:

```
 Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 4325036
```

You can solve this by going into the Google Play Store, and installing the update for Google Play services.

Answer (score 0):

I had the `Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error` when my wifi was down and I had a bad mobile internet connection. When I noticed that my wifi was off and I turned it on again and I had a good internet connection, the error was gone.